# Joining with another table by looking for maximum date under a criteria

Tags: sql, date, join, teradata, greatest-n-per-group

Edit: I’m using teradata sql assistant

I have two tables TABLE_1 and TABLE_2

TABLE_1: [image]

TABLE_2: [image]

And I want to left join TABLE_1 and TABLE_2 so that I am always taking the record that is of the most recent date from TABLE_2. The end result should look like: [image]

How do I specify my join condition?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TABLE_1.COLUMN_NUM,
TABLE_2.COLUMN_2
FROM TABLE_1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2
ON TABLE_1.COLUMN_NUM=TABLE_2.COLUMN_1 
AND TABLE_2.DATE = (MAXIMUM DATE FROM TABLE_2)
```

Comment: what is the DBMS name..??

Comment: @TheAG DBMS is Teradata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you wanted to write seems to be:

```
select t1.column_num, t2.column_2
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2
    on  t2.column_1 = t1.column_num 
    and t2.date = (
        select max(t22.date) from table_2 t22 where t22.column_1 = t1.column_1
    )
```

The downside, though, is that it requires two scans on `table_2`. For this dataset and expected resultset, I would recommend a correlated subquery with a row-limiting clause:

```
select
    t1.column_num,
    (
        select column2 
        from table_2 t2 
        where t2.column_1 = t1.column_num
        order by t2.date desc
        limit 1
    ) column_2
from table_1 t1
```

This is rather cross-database approach, although the syntax for the row-limiting clause may vary: the above would work in MySQL and Postgres, while SQL Server wants `select top (1) ... from ... where ... order by ...`.

This query would take advantage of an index on `table_2(column_1, date, column_2)` (thr ordering of the columns in the index matters here).

This query would take advantage of an index on `table_2(column_1, date, column_2)` (thr ordering of the columns in the index matters here).

If your database supports window functions, you can also `join` and use `row_number()`:

```
select t1.column_num, t2.column_2
from table_1 t1
left join (
    select t2.*, row_number() over(partition by column_2 order by date desc) rn
    from table_2 t2
) t2 on t2.column_1 = t1.column_num and t2.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which database you use, but for postgresql

`SELECT DISTINCT ON ( TABLE_1.COLUMN_NUM)TABLE_1.COLUMN_NUM, TABLE_2.COLUMN_2 FROM TABLE_1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_1.COLUMN_NUM=TABLE_2.COLUMN_1  ORDER BY TABLE_2.DATE  DESC`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below statement:

```
With temp AS(Select column_num, column_2, date, max(b.date) OVER (PARTITION BY b.column_1) max_dt
from table_1 a LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON a.column_num = b.column_1)

Select column_num, column_2 from temp
where date = max_dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as GMB's 3rd query, just filtering before the join using Teradata's proprietary QUALIFY clause:

```
select t1.column_num, t2.column_2
from table_1 t1
left join (
    select t2.*
    from table_2 t2
    qualify row_number()
            over(partition by column_2 
                 order by date desc) = 1
) t2
on t2.column_1 = t1.column_num
```